# How to import from a XML file into a Firebird table

Tags: xml, firebird

How can I import an XML file into a Firebird database table by executing a SQL statement?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE IMPORT_DATA
AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE xml_file_path VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE VARIABLE anlagen_nr INT;

BEGIN
  xml_file_path = 'PATH';
  device_number = NUMBER;

  INSERT INTO TABLE (ROW1, ROW2, ROW3)
  VALUES (
    :device_number,
    (SELECT CAST(X.Z.value('(Number)[1]', 'INT') AS INT) FROM XMLTABLE('/TopologyImportExport/DetectorZones/Zone' PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT :xml_file_path) COLUMNS Z XMLTYPE PATH '.')
    ),
    (SELECT X.Z.value('(Label)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)') FROM XMLTABLE('/TopologyImportExport/DetectorZones/Zone' PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT :xml_file_path) COLUMNS Z XMLTYPE PATH '.'))
  );
END
```

Comment: Firebird doesn't support parsing XML, so it doesn't have that `XMLTABLE` keyword and other related features. You could store XML data in a blob and retrieve it from a blob, but that is about it. You will need to parse the XML in your application, and insert it into the database, instead of trying to offload this to Firebird.

Answer (score 1):

To import XML into Firebird database you must use an external utility that parse XML file, transform data into relational form and then import it into the database. One of such utilities is [XMLWizard](http://www.guacosoft.com/xmlwizard/).

Comment: Yeah, i know but i want to create something for the biggest DAUs in my company

Comment: Firebird itself has no capacities to parse XML.

Comment: Have you other utilities?